# Drupal: Easy way to show a block above the main content?

Tags: drupal

is there some easy way to force drupal into showing a block ABOVE the main content for a page?

I have seen some examples that does this, but it involves some hacking into the theme to create a new region above the content. No simpler way in drupal 6?

Could the [Panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels) module help with this?

Big thank you for help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regions are defined by themes. Change your theme to Acquia Marina for instance ( http://drupal.org/project/acquia_marina ) which BTW requires Fusion Core ( http://drupal.org/project/fusion ). You'll get a region called `Content Top` which is above the Content Region. There are plenty of other regions you can find in this theme. If you want a good starter theme then you can use `Fusion Starter` theme (see link for Fusion Core).

Comment: In the theme you just add $content, so the order of the blocks is not defined by the theme? Really no way to control the order of the blocks inside Drupal?

Comment: @grm: Sure, there is a way to control the order of the blocks, just go to 'admin/build/block'. But you can only define the order per region, as blocks are only displayed in regions! So you need a theme with a region above the content in order to put a block there. BTW, it is not hard to [add a region to a theme](http://drupal.org/node/171224).

Comment: +1 comment @Henrik, yes adding a region to the theme should also suit grm well.

Comment: Yea, panels seems a bit of a overkill on what I want to achieve. I'm a bit new to drupal, but wouldn't changing the template in the theme break when I later do an upgrade of the theme?

Comment: @grm Yes that is true -- the modifications to the theme could break it during an upgrade. However, adding a region is not such a major thing, really. Make sure that when the theme is upgraded you can make sure the region is added again and does not interfere with anything. Also themes are different from modules -- once a theme is modified for your individual needs its not really common to "upgrade" it like you do for modules. The best approach to me would be to start with a theme that already offers you the "Content Top" region you're looking for (they would be many such themes).

Comment: @grm: What theme are you currently using BTW?

Comment: Yea, it was extremely easy. Thank you guys. I'm using blueprint

Answer (score 1):

With Panels, you can do all sorts of things with the layout of the content, and add to what is shown in the content area. Give it a try.

Comment: I sure will, but have a feeling it's a bit of a overkill for the simple site I'm creating. Thanks

Comment: Well not all themes are suited for all situations. Thats why things like Panels exist, and you could also adjust the theme .info file to create additional regions for blocks.